# Subtracting time from character column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am pulling two columns into my query. How do I subtract 5 hours from each column. Initially I tried (- interval '5 hours') from each, but I received a placement error.

```
to_char(orders.released_to_drivers_at at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'CST', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:MI am') "Available At (CST)",
to_char(order_cancellations.created_at at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'CST', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:MI am') "Canceled At (CST)"
```

```
to_char((orders.released_to_drivers_at at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'CST', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:MI am')- interval '5 hours') "Available At (CST)"
```

I tried the above query but received the below error

> ERROR: operator does not exist: record - interval Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 800

Comment: Actually showing the error you get is considered standard practice when asking questions. However, your brackets are clearly wrong in your second example since your `to_char` format is inside the inner brackets.

Comment: oh sorry, I incorporated the error into the question @RichardHuxton

Comment: The form is like: `select now() - interval '5 hrs';` or `select now() - '5 hrs'::interval;`. You need to do that before any other transformation.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added the full query into my question where exactly do I place the now() function

Comment: I was just showing an example, you should not be using `now()`. Assuming `orders.released_to_drivers_at` is a `timestamp` or `timestamptz` type you would need to do: `orders.released_to_drivers_at - '5 hrs'::interval` and then do your transformation on that value.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ok makes perfect sense thank you

Comment: Your parentheses are messed up, and `to_char` should be on the outside. But it seems that you are really struggling with time zone conversion, so this is an "XY problem". Perhaps edit the question and show the problem you are really trying to solve.